# Qt Using loadFromData got CRC error

Tags: qt, png

I using a char* array to create image, the original data is a PNG. And I'm sure it is, because I can read the PNG FILE header "137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10"

the code is follow:

```
QImage image;
bool ret = image.loadFromData((const uchar*)p->appIcon,p->iconSize, "PNG");
p_button->setIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(image.scaled(ICON_WIDTH,ICON_HIGH)));
....
```

But I got CRC error when it run:

```
libpng error: IDAT: CRC error
QImage::scaled: Image is a null image
Segmentation fault
```

Is there anyone can advice some reason can cause this error? Many many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're feeding bogus data to `loadFromData`. Just because the header is there, doesn't mean the rest of the data is there. My usual advice is: dump the data to a file and see if you can open it with an image editing program:

```
QByteArray data((const char*)p->appIcon, p->iconSize);
QFile file(QDir::homePath() + QDir::separator() + "test.png");
bool rc = file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
Q_ASSERT(rc);
qint64 n = file.write(data);
Q_ASSERT(n == data.size());
```

Comment: When I dump the data to file, I got unreadable file and the same CRC error.It is size problem. Thanks